# datepicker on webview is displayed strangely. on IphoneX

Tags: ios, jsp, datepicker, uiwebview

I'm a iOS Devleoper.
On iPhoneX, datePicker on WebView is displayed strangely.

I am calling the datepicker in the html file as follows:

`<body> <input type="date"> </body>`

Is there a workaround?

[DatePicker layout is incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSuCZ.png)

Comment: I tested this on the iOS 12 sim (albeit Xcode 10 beta still) and it worked fine, can you post a fully reproducible code snippet? I tested this with the following code in a new project and couldn't reproduce the bug you mention: `let wv = UIWebView(); view = wv; wv.loadHTMLString("<body><input type=\"date\"></body>", baseURL: nil);`